Will there be any problem with Ignite cluster and WAS communication? Ignite cluster(On-premise) <--> WAS-wildfly and etc(kubernetes)
When it to launch an Ignite cluster on-premises <--> containerize WAS with Kubernetes.
Here, it is a structure that connect Ignite cluster and WAS (e.g. wildfly or web application).
If you start with that structure, Will discoverySpi work well when a node restarts during the ignite cluster?
In Kubernetes, WAS has the IP/Port of the service object by creating a service (kubectl create -f service.yaml), so can discoverySpi find the instance IP/Port of ignite?
In other words, when the Ignite cluster restarts, there may be an issue where the Ignite cluster is unable to check discovery with WAS (e.g. wildfly).
Node search(DiscoverySPI) may not work. Is this okay? Can you tell if there are any problems?
(Will there be a problem with the service?)
Also, how should I set property name="???" in the code below Ignite cluster (on-premise) <-- connection -->WAS-wildfly(on kubernetes)?
code)

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
 
...
                            <property name="???" />
                            <property name="???" />
                            <property name="???" />
...

